# Why does this documentation example fail? Is my workaround an acceptable equivalent?

Tags: oop, raku

While exploring the documented example raised in this [perl6 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773986/how-to-add-subscripts-to-my-custom-class-in-perl-6) that was asked here recently, I found that the final implementation option - (my interpretation of the example is that it provides three different ways to do something) - doesn't work.  Running this;

```
class HTTP::Header does Associative {
    has %!fields handles <iterator list kv keys values>;

    sub normalize-key ($key)   { $key.subst(/\w+/, *.tc, :g)         }
    method EXISTS-KEY ($key)   { %!fields{normalize-key $key}:exists }
    method DELETE-KEY ($key)   { %!fields{normalize-key $key}:delete }
    method push (*@_)          { %!fields.push: @_                   }


    multi method AT-KEY (::?CLASS:D: $key) is rw {
        my $element := %!fields{normalize-key $key};

        Proxy.new(
            FETCH => method () { $element },

            STORE => method ($value) {
                $element = do given $value».split(/',' \s+/).flat {
                    when 1  { .[0] }    # a single value is stored as a string
                    default { .Array }  # multiple values are stored as an array
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

my $header = HTTP::Header.new;
say $header.WHAT;  #-> (Header)

$header<Accept> = "text/plain";
$header{'Accept-' X~ <Charset Encoding Language>} = <utf-8 gzip en>;
$header.push('Accept-Language' => "fr");    # like .push on a Hash

say $header<Accept-Language>.perl;          #-> $["en", "fr"]
```

... produces the expected output.  Note that the third last line with the `X` meta-operator assigns a literal list (built with angle brackets) to a hash slice (given a flexible definition of "hash").  My understanding is this results in three seperate calls to method `AT-KEY` each with a single string argument (apart from `self`) and therefore does not exersise the `default` clause of the `given` statement.  Is that correct?

When I invent a use case that excersises that part of the code, it appears to fail;

```
... as above ...
$header<Accept> = "text/plain";
$header{'Accept-' X~ <Charset Encoding Language>} = <utf-8 gzip en>;
$header{'Accept-Language'} = "en, fr,    cz";

say $header<Accept-Language>.perl;          #-> ["en", "fr", "cz"] ?? 

# outputs
(Header)
This Seq has already been iterated, and its values consumed
(you might solve this by adding .cache on usages of the Seq, or
by assigning the Seq into an array)
  in block  at ./hhorig.pl line 20
  in method <anon> at ./hhorig.pl line 18
  in block <unit> at ./hhorig.pl line 32
```

The error message provides an awesome explanation - the topic is a sequence produced by the split and is now spent and hence can't be referenced in the `when` and/or `default` clauses.

Have I correctly "lifted" and implemented the example?  Is my invented use case of several language codes in the one string wrong or is the example code wrong/out-of-date?  I say out-of-date as my recollection is that Seq's came along pretty late in the perl6 development process - so perhaps, this code used to work but doesn't now.  Can anyone clarify/confirm?

Finally, taking the error message into account, the following code appears to solve the problem;

```
       ... as above ...
       STORE => method ($value) {
            my @values = $value».split(/',' \s+/) ;
            $element = do given @values.flat {
                when 1  { $value  }   # a single value is stored as a string
                default { @values }   # multiple values are stored as an array
            }
        }
```

... but is it an exact equivalent?

Comment: You don't need to assign to an array, just add `.List` to the end: `$value».split(/',' \s+/).flat.List`

Answer (score 2):

That code works now (Rakudo 2018.04) and prints

```
$["en", "fr", "cz"]
```

as intended. It was probably a bug which was eventually solved.