# Proxy object for a hash?

Tags: object, hash, proxy, raku

How can I make a Proxy object for a hash?  I can't seem to find a way to pass in the hash key:

```
#sub attr() is rw {
sub attr($name) is rw {
  my %hash;
  Proxy.new(
    FETCH => method (Str $name) { %hash«$name» },
    STORE => method (Str $name, $value) { %hash«$name» = $value }
  );
}

my $attr := attr();
$attr.bar = 'baz';
say $attr.bar;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Proxy` is a substitute for a singular container aka [`Scalar`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar). A `Hash` is a plural container where each element is a `Pair`, with, by default, a `Scalar` for the value of the pair.

A possible solution (based on [How to add subscripts to my custom Class in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773986/how-to-add-subscripts-to-my-custom-class-in-perl-6/36785245#36785245)) is to delegate implementation of `Associative` to an internal hash but override the `AT-KEY` method to replace the default `Scalar` with a `Proxy`:

```
class ProxyHash does Associative {

  has %!hash handles
    <EXISTS-KEY DELETE-KEY push iterator list kv keys values gist Str>;

  multi method AT-KEY ($key) is rw {
    my $current-value := %!hash{$key};
    Proxy.new:
      FETCH => method ()       { $current-value },
      STORE => method ($value) { $current-value = $value }
  }
}

my %hash is ProxyHash;
%hash<foo> = 42;
say %hash; # {foo => 42}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.